# Почему не происходит отправка ajax запроса при изменении состояния чекбокса? Происходит редирект на пустую страницу

Tags: javascript, ajax

Помогите, пожалуйста

Есть таблица, в которой динамически (CRUD) создаются строчки с разными названиями, именами и т.д

У каждой такой строчки на конце стоит форма, и в ней чекбокс. (По сути чекбокс)

При нажатии на этот чекбокс должен отправляться ajax запрос, и значение чекбокса записывается в бд в виде 1/0, (on/off), и следовательно по этому параметру определяется состояние чекбокса (checked)

Конечно, страница не должна перезагружаться.

Код чекбокса

```
<form action="#" data-path="example">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</form>
```

Код на JS

```
let forms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form'));

    let onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let form = event.target;
        let url = $(form).data('path');
        let data = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: () => {
                console.log('Выбран');
            }
        })
    }

    forms.forEach(form => {
        let setListenerToCb = (elem) => {
            let checkBox = elem.querySelector('.check');
            checkBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
                form.submit();
            });
            form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
        }

        setListenerToCb(form);
    })
```

Проблема в том, что исполняющийся js скрипт не доходит до момента отправки ajax, он только отправляет саму форму и всё

Т.е код исполняется до момента

```
checkBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
                form.submit();
            });
```

А дальше всё

(на самом деле, происходит редирект на пустую страницу, но тут дело в контроллере, и в том, что я не могу отправить/принять ajax)

Что я не так делаю, и что можно изменить, помогите, пожалуйста

```js
let forms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form'));

    let onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let form = event.target;
        let url = $(form).data('path');
        let data = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: () => {
                console.log('Выбран');
            }
        })
    }

    forms.forEach(form => {
        let setListenerToCb = (elem) => {
            let checkBox = elem.querySelector('.check');
            checkBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
                form.submit();
            });
            form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
        }

        setListenerToCb(form);
    })
```

```html
<form action="#" data-path="example">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как указано в [справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event):

> Событие `submit` не происходит, если напрямую вызывается метод `.submit`

Если хочешь добавить проверку и отправлять `ajax` запрос, вызывай `OnSubmit` руками

```
checkBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    onSubmit(form);
});
```

изменив `onSubmit` так, чтобы передавался параметр `form`, а не события.